# Azure IOT Hub: Control a device connected to an IoT hub (Android)

Tags: android, message, device, azure-iot-hub, telemetry

Just followed the procedure explained in the quickstart ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-control-device-android), but unable to connect to the device to listen for direct method calls.
The sample app displayed an error message shown below.
Any sugg[image]estions to resolve this issue will be a great help.

Comment: i'm guessing you skipped/bungled this step since the error basically says it can't connect to the device you're trying to connect to "A device must be registered with your IoT hub before it can connect."

Comment: No, the device has been successfully registered in the Hub and able to send data to the azure storage. The problem is with the second sample - unable to listen for the direct api call.

Comment: it literally says IOThub not found, check your code to see if your hub ID is correct. i recommend you figure out logging in azure before running to stackoverflow with such a broad question

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like your simulated device is not connected to the Azure IoT Hub. Note, that the DirectMethod is a sync communication and the device must be connected and subscribed for this topic. Try to use a DeviceExplorer tool for testing your simulated devices from the Azure IoT Hub service-facing endpoints.

Comment: this issue has been resolved.

Comment: Could you describe how this issue has been resolved?

Comment: This tutorial consists of two parts:
#1: device API - this app sends the data from the android device to IOT hub.
#2: Service API - this app calls direct method to control the data frequency on the device connected to the hub.

I installed the app created in part#1 on my phone. This app pushes the data the to  hub using  events at reqular intervals.

I launched  the app in part #2 on another device keeping the first app running on my phone. 
This 2nd app just modifies the time interval and issues an event to the first app running on my phone.

Comment: In short: we need two devices
1. an IOT device and
2. another device to control the IOT device.

Comment: @Chandra add that as an answer and accept it yourself then

Comment: @Chandra have a look at an 'Azure IoT Hub Tester' https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester or MQTTBox client or MQTT.fx client, etc. for device side testing/simulation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial consists of two parts:
Part #1: Device API - This app sends the data from the android device to IOT hub.
Part #2: Service API - This app calls direct method to control the data frequency (sent time duration) on the device connected to the IOT hub.

I installed the app created in part#1 on my phone. This app pushes data to IOT  hub using  events at regular intervals.

I launched the app in part #2 on another device keeping the first app running on my phone.This 2nd app just modifies the time interval and issues an event to the first app running on my phone. A notification is displayed on the first app when the event is received.

In short: we need two devices
1. an IOT device connected to the hub.
2. another device to control the IOT device.

Comment: You are correct, you'd need two devices.  The scenario we are trying to simulate is an operator using Android to command another IoT devices (also happens to be Android in this tutorial but can be any device).